# How to merge Symfony form type attributes with attributes from form_row in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Suppose we have Symfony form type and a row adding field

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', ['attr' => ['class' => 'firstName', placeholder => 'first name']]);
```

I want this to be merged with attributes set in twig template:

```
{{ form_row(form.name, {'attr':{'class':'newClass'}}) }}
```

Currently it does replace. What is the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use form variables to get form class attr, then concatene another class attr:

```
{{ form_row(form.name, {'attr':{'class':'newClass ' ~ form.name.vars.attr.class|default('')}}) }}
```

EDIT:

Corrected my previous answer after reading https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-form-twig-variables

Comment: Cleaner way with merge, to avoid any possible duplicate : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html

Comment: @Aurelien it depends on how the class attr is defined in the formtype: if it's `"firstName newClass"`, `merge`won't avoid duplicate

Comment: Could still use twig split function to get around this though : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html